# How does the Jiva Volume Folder structure looks like? what are the files inside the folder

Tags: openebs

I have deployed one OpenEBS volume and seeing some default files like volume-head.img, volume-snap.img etc. I need to understand the folder structure of Jiva volume. I am assuming volume-snap.img is for snapshot. Is it a safe approach to keep snapshot related files inside the original volume? How we can recover data if the same volume goes for wrong?